# Regex with balancing groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex, balancing-groups

I need to write regex that capture generic arguments (that also can be generic) of type name in special notation like this:

```
System.Action[Int32,Dictionary[Int32,Int32],Int32]
```

lets assume type name is `[\w.]+` and parameter is `[\w.,\[\]]+`
so I need to grab only `Int32`, `Dictionary[Int32,Int32]` and `Int32`

Basically I need to take something if balancing group stack is empty, but I don't really understand how.

**UPD**

The answer below helped me solve the problem fast (but without proper validation and with depth limitation = 1), but I've managed to do it with group balancing:

```
^[\w.]+                                              #Type name
\[(?<delim>)                                         #Opening bracet and first delimiter
[\w.]+                                               #Minimal content
(
[\w.]+                                                       
((?(open)|(?<param-delim>)),(?(open)|(?<delim>)))*   #Cutting param if balanced before comma and placing delimiter
((?<open>\[))*                                       #Counting [
((?<-open>\]))*                                      #Counting ]
)*
(?(open)|(?<param-delim>))\]                         #Cutting last param if balanced
(?(open)(?!)                                         #Checking balance
)$
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5cw.%5d%2b%5c%5b(%3f%3cdelim%3e)%5b%5cw.%5d%2b(%5b%5cw.%5d%2b(%2c(%3f(open)%7c(%3f%3cparam-delim%3e)(%3f%3cdelim%3e)))*((%3f%3copen%3e%5c%5b))*((%3f%3c-open%3e%5c%5d))*)*%5c%5d(%3f(open)%7c(%3f%3cparam-delim%3e)(%3f%3cdelim%3e))%24&i=Action%5bInt%2cBool%2cDictionary%5bInt%2cbool%5d%5d)

**UPD2 (Last optimization)**

```
^[\w.]+
\[(?<delim>)
[\w.]+
(?:
 (?:(?(open)|(?<param-delim>)),(?(open)|(?<delim>))[\w.]+)?
 (?:(?<open>\[)[\w.]+)?
 (?:(?<-open>\]))*
)*
(?(open)|(?<param-delim>))\]
(?(open)(?!)
)$
```

Comment: Try [`\w+(?:\.\w+)*\[(?:,?(?<res>\w+(?:\[[^][]*])?))*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%2b(%3f%3a%5c.%5cw%2b)*%5c%5b(%3f%3a%2c%3f(%3f%3cres%3e%5cw%2b(%3f%3a%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d)%3f))*&i=System.Action%5bInt32%2cDictionary%5bInt32%2cInt32%5d%2cInt32%5d%0d%0a). The `${res}` captures will contain the values. You do not need any balancing groups here if you have 1 nested level of `[...]`. I am not even sure you need `\w+(?:\.\w+)*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest *capturing* those values using

```
\w+(?:\.\w+)*\[(?:,?(?<res>\w+(?:\[[^][]*])?))*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cw%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cw%2B)%2A%5C%5B(%3F%3A%2C%3F(%3F%3Cres%3E%5Cw%2B(%3F%3A%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D%2A%5D)%3F))%2A&i=System.Action%5BInt32%2CDictionary%5BInt32%2CInt32%5D%2CInt32%5D%0D%0A).

**Details:**

- `\w+(?:\.\w+)*` - match 1+ word chars followed with `.` + 1+ word chars 1 or more times
- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `(?:,?(?<res>\w+(?:\[[^][]*])?))*` - 0 or more sequences of:

  - `,?` - an optional comma
  - `(?<res>\w+(?:\[[^][]*])?)` - Group "res" capturing:

    - `\w+` - one or more word chars (perhaps, you would like `[\w.]+`)
    - `(?:\[[^][]*])?` - 1 or 0 (change `?` to `*` to match 1 or more) sequences of a `[`, 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`, and a closing `]`.

A [C# demo below](http://ideone.com/XVNjwj):

```
var line = "System.Action[Int32,Dictionary[Int32,Int32],Int32]";
var pattern = @"\w+(?:\.\w+)*\[(?:,?(?<res>\w+(?:\[[^][]*])?))*";
var result = Regex.Matches(line, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .SelectMany(x => x.Groups["res"].Captures.Cast<Capture>()
            .Select(t => t.Value))
        .ToList();
foreach (var s in result) // DEMO
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

**UPDATE**: To account for unknown depth `[...]` substrings, use

```
\w+(?:\.\w+)*\[(?:\s*,?\s*(?<res>\w+(?:\[(?>[^][]+|(?<o>\[)|(?<-o>]))*(?(o)(?!))])?))*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cw%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cw%2B)*%5C%5B(%3F%3A%5Cs*%2C%3F%5Cs*(%3F%3Cres%3E%5Cw%2B(%3F%3A%5C%5B(%3F%3E%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D%2B%7C(%3F%3Co%3E%5C%5B)%7C(%3F%3C-o%3E%5D))*(%3F(o)(%3F!))%5D)%3F))*&i=System.Action%5BInt32%2CDictionary%5BInt32%2CDictionary%5BInt32%2CInt32%5D%5D%2CInt32%5D%0D%0A)

Comment: Your solution helped me today and I was able to move on instantly, but then I've managed to solve it with balancing groups. Solution in updated question.

Comment: You actually could use a mod of my regex: [`\w+(?:\.\w+)*\[(?:\s*,?\s*(?<res>\w+(?:\[(?>[^][]+|(?<o>\[)|(?<-o>]))*(?(o)(?!))])?))*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%2b(%3f%3a%5c.%5cw%2b)*%5c%5b(%3f%3a%5cs*%2c%3f%5cs*(%3f%3cres%3e%5cw%2b(%3f%3a%5c%5b(%3f%3e%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%7c(%3f%3co%3e%5c%5b)%7c(%3f%3c-o%3e%5d))*(%3f(o)(%3f!))%5d)%3f))*&i=System.Action%5bInt32%2cDictionary%5bInt32%2cDictionary%5bInt32%2cInt32%5d%5d%2cInt32%5d%0d%0a). Your `[\w.]` matches substrings starting with `.` and that is wrong, since an identifier starts with `[a-zA-Z_]`